# Windows Forms Impersonation from a non-Domain added machine

Tags: c#, winforms, security

I would like to know if it is possible to perform an impersonation from an application that is running on a machine that is NOT added to the specified domain?

The application is a Windows Forms application. The WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name does not change after the impersonation has been done by calling UserLogon(), DuplicateToken() and Impersonate()

Is this something that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

Either you would need to add the machine to the domain or another trusted domain.

There may be something you could do with some custom key exchange protocol but ...